# How to make two class with the protocol of observable object access one another in swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have 2 class, both of which conform to observable object.  MusicController, which acts as part of a model for each music object that is created.  MusicCheck acts as a notifier for the UI when the application enters different states (willEnterForeground) and responds to the UI accordingly.

I am trying to allow both classes to have the ability to access one another.  I have them both setup as an EnvironmentObject, but this does not allow them to access one another as the app crashed because MusicController does not have access to the EnvironmentObject for MusicCheck.

When the music starts playing (in Music Controller) I would like to run a function in MusicCheck to change the variable value.  How can I allow the class MusicController to access the class MusicCheck?

```
class MusicController: ObservableObject {
@EnvironmentObject var musicCheck: MusicCheck
@Published var isPlaying = false

init() {
 // play the music and setup other sound logic

// Change the variable in MusicCheck
}
}



class MusicCheck: ObservableObject {
@Published var isPlayingAfter = false

init() {
  // perform logic for when the application willEnterForeground
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option, using `onAppear` to pass a reference to `musicCheck`:

```
class MusicController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPlaying = false
    var musicCheck : MusicCheck?
    
    func setup(musicCheck : MusicCheck) {
        self.musicCheck = musicCheck
        
        //perform other setup logic
    }
}

class MusicCheck: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPlayingAfter = false
    
    init() {
        // perform logic for when the application willEnterForeground
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var musicCheck = MusicCheck()
    @StateObject private var musicController = MusicController()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world")
        }.onAppear {
            musicController.setup(musicCheck: musicCheck)
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility is using a singleton pattern. I'd be cautious about this approach, as it can lead to situations that are challenging to test. Also, a mistake I see frequently is people creating a non-singleton instance and being confused about why they have multiple copies -- I've used a `private init` to try to avoid this.

```
class MusicController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPlaying = false
    
    init() {
        MusicCheck.shared.someFunction()
    }
}

class MusicCheck: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = MusicCheck()
    
    @Published var isPlayingAfter = false
    
    private init() {
        // perform logic for when the application willEnterForeground
    }
    
    func someFunction() {
        
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var musicCheck = MusicCheck.shared
    @StateObject private var musicController = MusicController()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world")
        }
    }
}
```